# Pygame Text overlap when i didnt use screen.fill(color),why?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying put the text on the PyGame window.

So i write the code as below：

If i don't set the window color, `screen.fill()`, my output text will overlap together i don't know why?

```
def game_12_4():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((1200, 800), p.RESIZABLE, 0)
    t = ""
    text = p.font.Font(None, 100).render(t, True, (255, 0, 0))
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = screen_rect.center
    while True:
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_UP:
                    t = "up"
                elif event.key == p.K_DOWN:
                    t = "down"
            text = p.font.Font(None, 100).render(t, True, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(screen, (0, 0))
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) ** <--------this cause the error**
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        p.display.flip()


game_12_4()
```

[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM53A.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `screen.blit(screen,(0,0))` causing the issue?  The code is blitting the screen onto itself.

Comment: No,when i mark screen.fill((255,255,255))  this command then run the script ,the word overlap on the screen, add this command, it shows correctly,press key up show the word "up" ,press key down shows the word "down"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i don't set the window color, screen.fill(), my output text will overlap together i don't know why?

Take a blackboard. Write the word 'up' on that blackboard. Now write 'down' on the exact same spot. As you can see, the words will overlap. That's what happening if you blit multiple surfaces onto the screen on the same spot.

Now back to the blackboard. Wipe it. Write the word 'up' on that blackboard. Wipe it again. Now write 'down' on the exact same spot as before. As you can see, the words will NOT overlap. See the difference?

When you blit a surface onto another (or fill a surface, or draw something on a surface with pygame's draw functions, or manipulate the pixel data manually, whatever) it's changed forever, until you change it again.

So, in summary, once you blit the 'up'-text-surface onto the screen surface, it will stay there until you paint over it (it does not magically remove itself), and the easiest way to do this is to just fill the entire screen with a solid color every frame (e.g. with `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))`).